# How many times is the paritioning method called in quicksort?

Tags: algorithm

If quick sort is run on an n sized array such that the array is always
divided into 2 equal halves. How many times is the partition algorithm
called?

Comment: Are you reposting a question under a different user? https://stackoverflow.com/q/66990622/10559142

Comment: Try to think through it on some small examples say 8 and 16 elements. Do you see a pattern?

Answer (score 0):

What you want to express is not very clear.
But I think it is 2+4+8+...+n, you can use the formula to calculate it.